# So i switched back to Classical SoundCloud and i'm in trap

Tags: soundcloud

I'm in the new web version of http://soundcloud.com
I click on an icon bubble with heart (Latest activities) and get and get page

"Oh no. Sorry! Something went wrong.
Is your network connection unstable or browser outdated?"

Everything is fine but if you click the "Switch back to classical SoundCloud" button on this page you get a trap. For me it is a classical soundcloud.com with a half working interface and button Switch to a new version which goes to nowhere. 
I get error stack in the webinspector

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 base.js:339
jQuery.extend.clean base.js:339
buildFragment base.js:326
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip base.js:319
jQuery.fn.extend.append base.js:308
SC.ATI.request base.js:1052
(anonymous function) base.js:1046
jQuery.extend.each base.js:31
SC.ATI.process base.js:1045
SC.ATI.push base.js:1052
(anonymous function) base.js:1465
jQuery.event.handle base.js:146
elemData.handle.eventHandle base.js:115
jQuery.event.trigger base.js:140
(anonymous function) base.js:182
jQuery.extend.each base.js:31
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each base.js:12
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger base.js:182
trackEvent base.js:1257
(anonymous function) base.js:1258
(anonymous function) base.js:1261
jQuery.event.handle base.js:146
elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

And i can't return a new version of the site and older one is not working. Only a full clear of cookies helps.

```
Environment:
Chrome Version 27.0.1453.93
Mac OS 10.7.5
```

So how can i view my activities in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact SoundCloud support [here](http://help.soundcloud.com). StackOverflow is only useful for programming related questions (i.e. using the SoundCloud API).

Answer (score 0):

If you're answer isn't already solved from contacting Soundcloud! Here's one!
On your browser (I'm using chrome) clear your browsing data! 
So you'll clear:
History,
Downloads,
Cookies,
The Cache (I think this is the one you want),
And I had; Data from hosted apps

This will revert the change back so your browser never knew you clicked on it!